# Windows Azure Storage - Table not found

Tags: visual-studio, azure, azure-storage

I'm trying to implement windows azure table storage...but I'm getting **'Table Not Found'**

Here is my connection string(How post I xml here?)(sorry for links)

ServiceConfiguration.Cloud.cscfg:
http://pastebin.com/F9tuckfT

ServiceConfiguration.Local.cscfg:

http://pastebin.com/XZHEvv6g

and here there's a print screen from my windows azure portal

http://s20.postimage.org/nz1sxq7hp/print.png

The code(sorry for the longer code...but there's three pages...Login works, when I log in, go to main.aspx that call grid.aspx ...In grid.aspx I get the error "Table not found" All this code is important for the question.....) http://pastebin.com/RnuvvqsM

I have tried

```
private void popula()
    {
        var account = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue("Conn"));
        account.CreateCloudTableClient().CreateTableIfNotExist("fiscal");
        var context = new CRUDManifestacoesEntities(account.TableEndpoint.ToString(), account.Credentials);

        Hashtable ht = (Hashtable)ViewState["filtro"];

        if (ht == null)
            GridView1.DataSource = context.SelectConc(ViewState["x"].ToString());
        else
            GridView1.DataSource = context.SelectConc(ht);

        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

but it doesn't work too

Other error similar is when I try to add a USER in table

```
public string addusr(string nome, string cidade, string cpf, string email, string telefone)
    {
        try
        {
            if (nome.Length == 0)
                return "f:Preencha o campo nome.";

            if (cidade.Length == 0)
                return "f:Preencha o campo cidade.";

            if (cpf.Length == 0)
                return "f:Preencha o campo cpf.";

            if (!Valida(cpf))
                return "f:CPF Invalido.";

            if (email.Length == 0)
                return "f:Preencha o campo email.";

            Regex rg = new Regex(@"^[A-Za-z0-9](([_\.\-]?[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*)@([A-Za-z0-9]+)(([\.\-]?[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*)\.([A-Za-z]{2,})$");
            if (!rg.IsMatch(email))
            {
                return "f:Email Invalido";
            }

            List<UserEntity> lst = new List<UserEntity>();
            var _account = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue("Conn"));
            _account.CreateCloudTableClient().CreateTableIfNotExist("fiscal");
            var _context = new CRUDUserEntities(_account.TableEndpoint.ToString(), _account.Credentials);


            var account = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue("Conn"));
            account.CreateCloudTableClient().CreateTableIfNotExist("fiscal");
            var context = new CRUDUserEntities(account.TableEndpoint.ToString(), account.Credentials);
            UserClientEntity entity = new UserClientEntity() { nome = nome, cidade = cidade, cpf = cpf, email = email, telefone = telefone };
            context.ADDUSociate(entity);
            context.SaveChanges();
            return "k";
        }
```

I'm getting this error:    
**f:An error occurred while processing this request.| at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceContext.SaveResult.HandleBatchResponse()
 at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceContext.SaveResult.EndRequest()
 at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceContext.SaveChanges(SaveChangesOptions options)
 at AzureTableLayer.CRUDUserEntities.ADDUSociate(UserClientEntity entity)
 at mobile.Service1.addusr(String nome, String cidade, String cpf, String email, String telefone)**

I believe that the two problems are related

**EDIT:** I have debugged and discovered that the StorageClient framework could not be loaded...
I'm getting this error Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'

How to solve?

Comment: Before I answer, I see that you've included actual credentials in the config file. Please either remove that from the config file or regenerate your account key to avoid misuse of your storage account.

Comment: Can you share the code where you're getting this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API has been changed. you need to do it like this:

```
var key = CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("Setting1");
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(key);
var client = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();

CloudTable table = client.GetTableReference(ContactTableName);
table.CreateIfNotExists();
```

Answer (score 1):

How are you trying to work with Table Storage? Trought the .NET SDK? PHP? Java? Node? ... Typically if you get this error it means that... the table does not exist.

Check the SDK you're using for a method similar to [CreateIfNotExists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.table.cloudtable.createifnotexists.aspx) in order to create the table before you start using it.

**Edit:**

The issue probably happens here:

```
        var account = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue("Conn"));
        var context = new CRUDManifestacoesEntities(account.TableEndpoint.ToString(), account.Credentials);

        Hashtable ht = (Hashtable)ViewState["filtro"];

        if (ht == null)
            GridView1.DataSource = context.SelectConc(ViewState["x"].ToString());
        else
            GridView1.DataSource = context.SelectConc(ht);
```

Add the following code after the var `account = ...` line:

```
     account.CreateCloudTableClient().CreateTableIfNotExist("<name of your table>");
```

Comment: if is Windows Azure table storage, only can be .net

Comment: No, Windows Azure is an open platform, not restricting you to .NET - there are plenty of SDKs available, like for Node.js: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/nodejs/how-to-guides/table-services/

Comment: Show us some code please. The only thing you need to do is probably something like `table.CreateIfNotExist();` to fix your issue.

Comment: I'm trying `protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue("Conn"));
            CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            // Retrieve a reference to a container 
            CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("fiscal");
            // Create the container if it doesn't already exist
            container.CreateIfNotExist();

        }` is uploading...

Comment: Please add it to your questions (it's hard to read like this). Also try to explain what you're trying to do and where it's failing.

Comment: `var account =CloudStorageAccount.Parse(RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue("Conn"));
account = account.CreateCloudTableClient().CreateTableIfNotExist("<name of your table>");
        var context = new CRUDManifestacoesEntities(account.TableEndpoint.ToString(), account.Credentials);

        Hashtable ht = (Hashtable)ViewState["filtro"];

        if (ht == null)
            GridView1.DataSource = context.SelectConc(ViewState["x"].ToString());
        else
            GridView1.DataSource = context.SelectConc(ht); `?

Comment: I did put  `account.CreateCloudTableClient().CreateTableIfNotExist("<name of your table>");` everywhere after `account =`